# bash script is giving me an error when it runs on MAC terminal

Tags: bash, scripting

myfirst.sh is the file and the code I have is -

```
#! /bin/bash

number = 1

while [ $number -lt 10 ]
do
    echo "$number"
    number=$(( number+1 ))
done
```

when I run this I get the following error

```
./myfirst.sh: line 3: number: command not found
./myfirst.sh: line 5: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove spaces when assigning 1 to number

```
#! /bin/bash

number=1

while [ $number -lt 10 ]
do
    echo "$number"
    number=$(( number+1 ))
done
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```